# CSS not working on a page accessed via internal link to an id tag

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm pretty new to web development, and I'm just attempting to make my first practice website, but I'm having a problem. The main content is on a page full of poetry called disobedient-poems.html. Each poem has it's own heading with it's own id tag, like this:

`<h3 class="poem-heading" id="today">Today</h3>`

Each poem is written within it's own p tag under the h3 headings which all have the same class attribute, like this:

`<p class="poems">blah blah blah</p>`

The CSS I've used to style the page works fine when I click on the html file for that page to view it in Safari. But if I access that page via an internal link that links to a specific part of that page by adding the id tag at the end of the link, like this:

`<a href="disobedient-poems.html/#today">Today</a>`

The link works but the CSS no longer does on that page. If I go back to the disobedient-poems.html file in the folder it's in and open that directly, the CSS works. The main navigation on the whole site works properly from page to page and the CSS file is linked correctly to each page, the CSS just doesn't work when clicking on an internal link that links to an id tag.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove / <a href="disomovebedient-poems.html#today">Today</a>

Comment: @Dmitriy I only just saw this comment, but this worked! I'll remember to not add the / in future. Thanks a lot, buddy!

Answer (score 0):

The "#" tag for was made specifically for one-paged websites especially blogs for people to easily access it but about the CSS, I've never encountered it, can you try pasting the code?

Comment: No need buddy, I figured it out now. But thanks for attempting to help. Really appreciate it!